# How to map JSON keys to properties in a class in groovy?

Tags: json, groovy

I've got the following class:

```
class Account {
def name
def location
def balance 
}
```

and the following Json:

```
{"name": "John Doe", "current_location": "New York", "balance": "5000" }
```

When I deserialize the above JSON (for example using `JsonSlurper`) to the Account class, is there a way of mapping "`current_location`" to location, with name and balance being automatically mapped? something like `@JsonProperty("current_location")` in Java?

Comment: `@JsonProperty("current_location")` should still work. how do you marshall your objects?

Comment: well I just wanted to convert the data from the response given by RestTemplate to instances of my class.

Comment: I meant RESTClient

Comment: Transform the key and use the map c'tor of Account?